# SQL to choose filters with OR in between C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a window app that show some values of columns as a check box,
as example: column name "DD_14 : did you search for job ?" so the answers yes and no is as check box.

What I want is to see the distribution of cases who choose yes from DD_14, Or  No from another column as example DD_15.

I just need to edit the query but it is written this way:

```
string sql_filter_part1 = "";
if (cb_DD_14_A_DESC_Yes.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part1 = sql_filter_part1 + " " + @"""DD_14_A_SEQ_NO""::int=1 ";
}
if (cb_DD_14_A_DESC_No.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part1 = sql_filter_part1 + " " + @"""DD_14_A_SEQ_NO""::int=2 ";
}
if (cb_DD_14_A_DESC_NotSelected.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part1 = sql_filter_part1 + " " + @"""DD_14_A_SEQ_NO"" is null ";
}

if (sql_filter_part1.Length > 0)
{
    sql_filter_part1 = sql_filter_part1.Trim();
    sql_filter_part1 = sql_filter_part1.Replace("  ", " or ");
    sql_filter_part1 = "(" + sql_filter_part1 + ")";
}
```

and other column:

```
string sql_filter_part2 = "";
if (cb_DD_14_B_DESC_1.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2 + " " + @"""DD_14_B_SEQ_NO""::int=1 ";
}
if (cb_DD_14_B_DESC_2.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2 + " " + @"""DD_14_B_SEQ_NO""::int=2 ";
}
if (cb_DD_14_B_DESC_3.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2 + " " + @"""DD_14_B_SEQ_NO""::int=3 ";
}
if (cb_DD_14_B_DESC_4.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2 + " " + @"""DD_14_B_SEQ_NO""::int=4 ";
}
if (cb_DD_14_B_DESC_NotSelected.Checked)
{
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2 + " " + @"""DD_14_B_SEQ_NO"" is null ";
}
if (sql_filter_part2.Length > 0)
{
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2.Trim();
    sql_filter_part2 = sql_filter_part2.Replace("  ", " or ");
    sql_filter_part2 = "(" + sql_filter_part2 + ")";
}
sql_filter = sql_filter_part1 + " " + sql_filter_part2 + " " + sql_filter_part3 + " " + sql_filter_part4 + " " + sql_filter_part5;
```

and save them into class, this class will be run in procedure after check box checked.

So the point is I want to see the filter whether user check yes in column 1 or check yes in column 2.

Comment: Start by rewriting this query normally, using parameters and without all the concatenation. You may find it easier, and will get more help on [so] probably also

Comment: The query composition depending on the conditions can be done easily with the help of LINQ-like ORM. Can you use any?

Comment: I will try, work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot that you can (and should) do to clean up your code and make it less repetitive and error-prone, using object-oriented principles. But I think something like this could be made to work:

```
var parts = new[] 
  {
    sql_filter_part1,
    sql_filter_part2,
    sql_filter_part3,
    sql_filter_part4,
    sql_filter_part5
  };
var activeParts = parts.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p));
sql_filter = string.Join(" or ", activeParts);
```